# cx_Oracle string representation of to_date() throws an error

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I am constructing a dynamic update statement based on values from a dict.

```
dict1 = {"name": "Test name",
         "id": 100,
         "location": "",
         "custom": "01/01/2020"}

print(dict1)
print()
dict2 = {}
func1 = 'to_date({}, "dd/mm/yyyy")'
for k, v in dict1.items():
    if k == 'custom':
        v = func1.format(f'"{v}"')

    dict2[k] = v

print(dict2)
```

```
{'name': 'Test name', 'id': 100, 'location': '', 'custom': 'to_date("01/01/2020", "dd/mm/yyyy")'}
```

dictionary is built as it's expected because **func1** is defined as a string. However I am trying to see if there is a way I could change **'to_date("01/01/2020", "dd/mm/yyyy")'** stored in dict as **to_date("01/01/2020", "dd/mm/yyyy")** without single quote (not string)

I am using this value in further processing to oracle using cx_oracle. Update statement is which would throw an error **'ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected'**

```
update table1 set dt='to_date("01/01/2020", "dd/mm/yyyy")' where x=y
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: "However I am trying to see if there is a way I could change 'to_date("01/01/2020", "dd/mm/yyyy")' stored in dict as to_date("01/01/2020", "dd/mm/yyyy")" Do you mean "to" rather than "as"? And do you mean you want the value of `to_date("01/01/2020", "dd/mm/yyyy")` stored in the dictionary?

Comment: yes, looking to store ```to_date("01/01/2020", "dd/mm/yyyy")``` in dict

Comment: I think those single quotes you're worried about are a byproduct of printing out the variable, but your other problem is that you are using double quotes in your Oracle query when you really want single quotes: set dt=to_date('01/01/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') where x = y

Comment: You appear to be hardcoding data into the SQL statement text. In general, this will be a performance and security issue.  Use a bind variable to keep the data separate.  See the warning and example in https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#sql-queries (which applies to UPDATE too).  In your case you would want the SQL statement to be `... to_date(:bv, 'dd/mm/yyyy') where ...` and then bind in the value `01/01/2020`.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `to_date()` in the SQL statement and bind only the data itself:

```
dict1 = {"name": "Test name",
         "id": 100,
         "location": "wherever",
         "custom": "01/01/2020"}

sql = """update table1 set dt=to_date(:custom, 'dd/mm/yyyy') where id=:id and location=:location and name = :name"""

cursor.execute(sql, dict1)
```

Note the bind variable names match the dict key names.

cx_Oracle documentation on binding is [here](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html).